# Java - Ask for algorithms for graphics movements

Tags: java, algorithm, swing, graphics, actionlistener

I'm doing a practice of Graphics in java with movement by using Timer. I created 2 graphic objects and then wanna them change position together as image below:

[image]

And this is my code:

```
 import java.awt.Color;
 import java.awt.Dimension;
 import java.awt.Font;
 import java.awt.Graphics;
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;
 import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
 import javax.swing.Timer;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DrawingGraphicObject extends JFrame {

// Define named-constants
private static final int CANVAS_WIDTH = 640;
private static final int CANVAS_HEIGHT = 480;
private static final int UPDATE_PERIOD = 50; // milliseconds
private DrawCanvas canvas; // the drawing canvas (an inner class extends JPanel)

// Attributes of moving object
private int w = 150, h = 90; // width and height
private int gap = 20;
private int x1 = 100, y1 = 100; // top-left (x, y)
private int x2 = x1 + w + gap, y2 = y1;
// private int x2, y2;
private int xSpeed = 7, ySpeed = 9; // displacement per step in x, y

// Limited Points
private int limX1 = x1 + w + gap;
private int limY1 = y1 + h + gap;
private int limX2 = x2 - gap - w;
private int limY2 = y2 - gap - h;

// Variables which is used to save the starting position 
private static final int y1Temp = 100;
private static final int y2Temp = 100;

// Constructor to setup the GUI components and event handlers
public DrawingGraphicObject() {
    canvas = new DrawCanvas();
    canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT));
    this.setContentPane(canvas);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.pack();
    this.setTitle("Bouncing Ball");
    this.setVisible(true);

    // Define an ActionListener to perform update at regular interval
    ActionListener updateTask = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            update(); // update the (x, y) position
            repaint(); // Refresh the JFrame, callback paintComponent()
        }
    };
    // Allocate a Timer to run updateTask's actionPerformed() after every delay msec
    new Timer(UPDATE_PERIOD, updateTask).start();
}

// Update the (x, y) position of the moving object
public void update() {
    y1 += ySpeed;
    if (y1 >= limY1) {
        y1 = limY1;
        x1 += xSpeed;
        if (x1 >= limX1) {
            x1 = limX1;
            if (y1 != y2Temp) {
                y1 -= ySpeed;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("x1: " + x1 + " y1: " + y1 + " lim y1: " + limY1 + " y2Temp: " + y2Temp);

    y2 -= ySpeed;
    if (y2 <= limY2) {
        y2 = limY2;
        x2 -= xSpeed;
        if (x2 < limX2) {
            x2 = limX2;
            if (y2 != y1Temp) {
                y2 += ySpeed;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("x2: " + x2 + " y2: " + y2 + " lim y2: " + limY2 + " y1Temp: " + y2Temp);
}

// Define inner class DrawCanvas, which is a JPanel used for custom drawing
private class DrawCanvas extends JPanel {
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); // paint parent's background
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20);

        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRoundRect(x1, y1, w, h, 20, 20);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawString("1", x1 + w / 2, y1 + h / 2);
        g.setFont(font);

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRoundRect(x2, y2, w, h, 20, 20);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString("2", x2 + w / 2, y2 + h / 2);
        g.setFont(font);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new DrawingGraphicObject();
        }
    });
}
}
```

It didn't work correctly, i.e: object-1 move down, move right, and then just a short moving up. I think the problem is in update() method, I tried to change other algorithms but it's impossible. Please help this everybody.
Thanks.

Comment: Quit shouting. There is no need to capitalize your question title. Learn by example how other ask questions.

Comment: @camickr yup, sorry about that.

Comment: The problem seems to be that as soon as it goes up (y1 -= ySpeed) then y1 is no longer >= limY1, so it will immediately go down again. You need to keep track of what direction it is supposed to be going, with, say, dx and dy variables. Change their sign or set them to zero whenever a limit is hit, and add them to the x, y coordinates at every update.

Comment: @DavidConrad ok thanks a lot for your idea bro, I fixed it.